# WMI event notification in C++

Tags: c++, events, wmi, wql

Can anyone help me in writing the `WMI` query to get event notification when a speaker or headphone/MIC is connected to my system. I tried `SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN .1 TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_SoundDevice'`. But it doesn't seems working.

I am coding in `C++`.